# JS Smooth scroll not working (still snapping)

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to have a smooth scroll feature that uses div id="" but instead of scrolling it snaps to the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/T6F6v/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {

var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top;

$('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 500, function(target){
    window.location.hash = target;
});

e.preventDefault();
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() {` is missing the closing `})`. That's all.

**Edit:** as the conversation on Calamari's answer suggests, `$('html,body').animate({...` is necessary for cross-browser compatibility. Firefox and IE only respond to `html`, while Chrome only responds to `body`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it now prevents it from scrolling all together now?

Comment: @user2588644, I've updated it after some cross-browser testing. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you, I've added the closing tag and the ',body'. The reasoning it wasn't working when I first tried was because I was in chrome and did not think browsers affected online code editors.

Answer (score 0):

Besides of that you miss a closing `});` you should write `$('html,body').animate(...`, instead of only writing `$('html').animate(...`. That should do the trick.

Comment: What does adding `,body` do differently, and why is it preferable?

Comment: It allows webkit browsers to work, too. And in my opinion it should only be `body`, but somehow firefox seems to scroll on the html.

Comment: Only `body` doesn't scroll at all in his fiddle, and `html,body` behaves the same as `html`, so `body` arguably doesn't contribute anything.

Comment: What browser are you trying with?

Comment: Firefox and IE10 (didn't check earlier versions yet) only respond to `html`, while Chrome (which I didn't try until you asked me that) only responds to `body`. Fascinating